# Which hard disk encryptions schemes are tied to the original hardware?

Tags: encryption, defense

When using a laptop, an encrypted HD/SSD can be an important security measure. However, laptops are prone to accidents (fluid spills, dropping on the floor, etc) that may mandate some or all of the components to be replaced.

**Are there hard disk encryption schemes that tie the encryption key to other hardware than the HD?**

Meaning the drive would be unreadable when it's plugged into a machine other than the (destroyed) original one. Just to avoid them when using a laptop ;-)

Comment: Why would you *tie the encryption key to some hardware* part?

Comment: I don't know and I don't want to. I thought there might some schemes that do it, especially when they use the TPM. That's why I asked this question - just to be sure I can access my data when the rest of the computer is gone.

Comment: If so, most of open-source tools would do the job as you mean, by default. Linking HW to something like salt is possible, but is not usual (it's a *not so good* idea). Well, @Polynomial answer, like mine, are quite right.

Answer (score 1):

None that I know of. The standard for disk encryption is [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/), which accepts a password, key files, and smart cards as authentication credentials.

So, at worst, you could use your key files if you put them on a single drive and it fails. Of course, that should be a moot point since you're doing regular backups, right? ;)

Comment: TrueCrypt is hardly *the* standard, even on Windows (there's Bitlocker!). On Linux, it's available but hardly ever used except for containers that must also be accessible from Windows.

Comment: I've often heard it described as the standard, and I don't know of another free open-source cross-platform solution that's as pervasive as TC is.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edited 2015-03-23

As this question was asked by a window user, my answer is not appropriate.

But from time @polynomial answered, his recommendation *truecrypt* is become **unsecured**.

Today *cryptsetup* continue to work fine, but a *standard* was appeared: [*LUKS* for *Linux Unified Key Setup*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) (based  on cryptsetup)

... If you really wanna be secured, switch to open-source softwares, like [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/goals.html) or [Debian](https://www.debian.org/security/)!

#### Original post

Under *GNU/Linux*, there is a *standardization effort*: [cryptsetup](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/)

and some (older project) like [cryptmount](http://cryptmount.sourceforge.net/).

Both suites are based on (same) kernel crypto modules and could accept a *passphrase*. When installed on *root* file system, the passphrase will be asked at boot (before mounting root `/`).

Both suites use the block device abstraction layer [dm-setup](http://sourceware.org/dm/) present as standard in Linux kernel from version 2.6.

Quite simple to install, but some linux experience may be useful.

Comment: And this software is not tying the encryption to some hardware id, right? The passphrase protects the encryption key which is stored somewhere on the hard drive?

Comment: Right, however, there was some (older) version of cryptmount who build key from a derivation of passphrase (hash), so passphrase could not be changed. Newer version use a self generated key, protected by the passphrase. But there is no link to hardware ID (not now and not prior)...( Unless you modify mount script ;-)