# Is there a hard-to-spoof identifier associated with a physical hard disk

Tags: key-management, forensics, disk-encryption

I would like to salt the pass phrase with the drive id in such a way that, if the disk were imaged to a new drive with a different id, ([e.g. by a government forensics specialist)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30912/what-do-i-need-to-be-aware-of-to-select-a-transfer-method-for-digital-forensic-d) then the image would be unusable even with a correct pass phrase.

NB: [Which hard disk encryptions schemes are tied to the original hardware?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29868/which-hard-disk-encryptions-schemes-are-tied-to-the-original-hardware) asks exactly the opposite question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no benefit to using physical disk information as a salt. It's security by obscurity. The forensics specialist could just hard-code the previous drive's information into the decryption software.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of off the top of my head that would do this would be a TPM in the machine, but there's always one problem no matter what you're doing:

If they have access to your drive to clone it, they probably have access to the rest of your machine.

So, even if you have something that is hard to spoof, there's a chance they may not even need to spoof it.